# How to install Latex in Ubuntu Mate

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to install Latex in Ubuntu mate. I tried with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install texmaker
sudo apt-get install texlive full
```

But after the second command it is showing that it is Unable to locate package.
Any package I am missing to add ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The packages are called `texmaker` and `texlive`, where did the `full` come from?

Comment: @Jos There is also a `texlive-full` I am not sure what is the differences between `texlive-full` and `texlive`.

Comment: @user68186 Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

You missed a **`-`** in between `texlive` and `full`. The second command should be:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Hope this helps